# RVM, Merb, Rake and RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, merb, rvm

I am currently running ruby-1.9.1 installed via RVM. I have been looking at using Merb, but when I try and run it I get this error:

```
  sam@shiny-dev:~/Projects/mojo$ rake db:migrate
    (in /home/sam/Projects/mojo)
    Merb root at: /home/sam/Projects/mojo
    /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378@merb/gems/dm-validations-1.0.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OrderedHash
    Loading init file from ./config/init.rb
    Loading ./config/environments/development.rb
    rake aborted!
    no such file to load -- spec/rake/spectask
    /home/sam/Projects/mojo/Rakefile:24:in `require'
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have installed rspec, but even in IRB I cannot require 'spec/rake/spectask' unless I also install rspec-rails (which I have now done).

Any ideas where I could even start?

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 weeks I finally figured it out!

Edit your Gemfile and add the line:

```
gem "rspec", :require => "spec"
```

and you're away!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with this on Rails 2.3.5. I ended up having to uninstall RSpec 2.0 and install RSpec 1.3.0 instead.